# How do I link this dynamic-link library to the program?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking

I have exported

> /home/username/mesa/lib

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and tried to link the libraries, but I do not know what I have type wrong to compile the program.

So I tried to compile testing.cpp with the g++ command and it says :

```
 fatal error: osmesa.h: No such file or directory
 #include <osmesa.h>
```

I suppose I have typed wrong the command.

The command I tried: `g++ testing.cpp -L/home/username/mesa/lib/libOSMesa.so -lmesa -s -Lmesa -lOSMesa -lGLU`

Source code of testin.cpp:

```
#include <osmesa.h>

int main() 
{
return 0; 
}
```

libraries in side `/home/username/mesa/lib`:

> libOSMesa.la libOSMesa.so libOSMesa.so.8 libOSMesa.so.8.0.0

Comment: By the way, excellent job on learning how to run the compiler manually ! Once you get the hang of it though, I recommend reading on Gnu Makefiles and then on CMake to make your life easier !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the include directories as well, use the `-I` compiler option.
This is because the compiler will by default not look for headers in your home directory (it will do that for system installed libraries in /usr/include).